# AWS Lex : An error has occurred: Invalid Lambda Response

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-lex

I am trying to save the values gathered with Amazon Lex into DynamoDB.
I made (or copied and modified) a Lambda function, which obviously does not work, but I really don't understand why.
This is the error I get from Amazon Lex : "An error has occurred: Invalid Lambda Response: Received error response from Lambda: Handled"

Everything else works fine, I solved a permission issue, and other errors I got.

When I get that error, the dialog is at state :

```
{
   "dialogState": "ElicitSlot",
   "intentName": "MCQ_A",
   "message": "What is a black and white horse",
   "messageFormat": "PlainText",
   "responseCard": null,
   "sessionAttributes": {},
   "slotToElicit": "QB",
   "slots": {
       "QA": "4",
       "QB": null,
       "Session": "444"
   }
}
```

// Here is my Lambda function. It is written in javascript, which I just discovered, and which I am absolutely not comfortable with ^^'

```
console.log('Loading event');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});
var tableName = "MCQ";

// Close dialog with the customer, reporting fulfillmentState of Failed or Fulfilled
function close(session_attributes, m) {
    let callback_obj = {
        sessionAttributes: session_attributes,
        dialogAction: {
            type: 'Close',
            fulfillmentState: "Fulfilled",
            message: m,
        }
    }
    return callback_obj;
}

function storeRegistration(intent, callback) {

    let userInfo = {};

    // store every slot we received as part of registration
    Object.keys(intent.slots).forEach((item) => {
        console.log(item)
        userInfo[item] = {"S": intent.slots[item]};
    });

    dynamodb.putItem({
        "TableName": tableName,
        "Item" : userInfo
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Failure storing user info');
            console.log(err);
            callback(close(intent.sessionAttributes, {contentType: 'PlainText', content: "I am sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again."}));
        } else {
            console.log("Successfully Stored UserInfo");
            callback(close(intent.sessionAttributes, {contentType: 'PlainText', content: "Thank you for attending the MCQ."}));
        }
    });
}

// --------------- Main handler -----------------------

// Route the incoming request based on intent.
// The JSON body of the request is provided in the event slot.
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log(event);
    try {
        storeRegistration(event, (response) => {callback(null, response)});
    } catch (err) {
        callback(err);
    }
};
```

Do you have any idea what's going on ? :)
Thank you very much in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FOUND A SOLUTION :

I gave up my function and took the blueprint by AWS called lex-order-flowers-python. It works out of the box with the Lex blueprint OrderFlowers. I just had to adapt it to my work, and add the DynamoDB part.

Make sure that your Item is in the good format, with the value type specified ('S' for a String)

```
put_item(
    TableName = 'myTableName',
    Item = {
        'key1': {'S': 'value1'}
        'key2': {'S': 'value2'}
    })
```

So I made this :

```
userInfo = {}
for key, value in intent_request['currentIntent']["slots"].items() :
    userInfo[key] = {'S': value}

logger.debug(userInfo)

dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
dynamodb.put_item(TableName='MCQ', Item=userInfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The slot **QB** may be checked as **required** in the slots definition area. Eventhough you are closing the dialog by fulfilling the intent, the lex following its priorities so that it eliciting the slot.
2. Handle the elicitSLot criteria from code end not from lex console.

Comment: Uncheck the required tag for the slot `QB` and try with your existing code itself. For elicit slot what you have updated in your code is not the correct way to do.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answer. QB is set as 'required' indeed.
So I added some lines to handle this case in the main section:

```
if (event.dialogState == "ElicitSlot")
        callback(null, {
            "dialogAction": {
                "type": "ElicitSlot",
                "intentName": event.intentName,
                "slots": event.slots,
                "slotToElicit" : event.slotToElicit
        }})
```

But I get the same error. In my despair I also tried with a 'Delegate' response, but same error also.
I have the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html#using-lambda-input-event-format) with me so I guess my responses are properly written.
Still, I don't understand why my chatbot returns an output with an empty slot, since I actually fill the slot in the dialog ...

EDIT : After a few test with AWS's blueprint "order flowers" and the corresponding lambda function, everything works smoothly until I add a line for storing into Dynamodb. So my mistake must be there.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, you should add these details to your question above by clicking "edit" under your question. You've actually added this as an answer to your own question. And could you include this new code in the full code snippet above so we can see where in this runs, please? Thanks.